# Error while updating property color on shadow node of type: AndroidTextInput

Tags: java, android, react-native

[image: getting this error**strong text**]

I don't know when and where this error appeared, so I cant attach any code. This looks like bug, on ios work properly. Is error tells that I should set Integer as property color? What?

Do someone know what should I do, thanks

Comment: how do you set the textinput color programmatically or in xml? judging by mistake - programmatically.

Comment: yes, I set it programmatically

Comment: can you show this code. where you set color

Comment: I set color in much cases, idk where it fails

Comment: then one thing can help in your case. to track the place of this error, set in the settings of the developer mode on the phone - 1.always show message of error 2. show all ANR

Comment: When I created the fresh ReactNative project and moved the code (only the source code, package.json and configuration files) to it, the error was gone. I am clueless what was the difference, but it cured the error.